# Flutter - Error when trying to build on iOS: error: type 'Profile' has no member 'PictureMode'

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

When I try to run my project on iOS simulator I get the following error:

```
Xcode's output:
↳
/Users/tommitchell/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_login_facebook-0.2.1/ios/Classes/SwiftFlutterLoginFacebookPlugin.swift:178:61: error: type 'Profile' has no member 'PictureMode'
                let url = profile.imageURL(forMode: Profile.PictureMode.normal,
                                                    ~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
```

Can someone explain how to resolve this?

Comment: Is there a solution?